# Passing Qt classes by const reference

Tags: c++, qt, reference, copy-on-write

It's known that Qt classes use [copy-on-wite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) when passing by value. So copy isn't done until its needed. I have seen many times passing Qt classes by const reference when only needed read-only access to object. Why do people pass `const QString&` instead of simple `QString` if in both cases no copy is done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because magic comes with a price. QString doesn't copy entire string, but it calculates references. Many copyings of QString can slow down the program. If `const QString&` is sufficient for your needs, why not use it? It is still faster.

Answer (score 8):

Copy on write does not mean, that object will not be copied. It only means that *deep copy* will be made  on write, i.e. actual *data* will be copied on write.  Main complexity of making a copy is of course in that *data* copying. But just making a shallow copy involves some operations, like reference counting.

In result, *passing by reference is still cheaper, than making shallow copy*.